# not able to filter array to get movies on react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function called `handleDelete` that takes in a `movie` object and will filter based on which `movie` is passed. When I click it, I get the error `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`.

Update: Posted all of the code.

**JS**

```
handleDelete = (movie) => {
    const movies = this.setState.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id);
    this.setState({ movies });
};
```

**JSX**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../services/fakeMovieService";
import { getMovies } from "../services/fakeMovieService";

class MovieTable extends Component {
   state = {
   movies: getMovies()
};

render() {
   return (<table className="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Genre</th>
        <th scope="col">Stock</th>
        <th scope="col">Rate</th>
        <th> </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {this.state.movies.map(movies => (
        <tr key={movies._id}>
          <td> {movies.title} </td>
          <td> {movies.genre.name}</td>
          <td> {movies.numberInStock} </td>
          <td> {movies.dailyRentalRate}</td>
          <td
            onClick={movie => this.handleDelete(movie)}
            className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
          >
            Delete
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>);
}}

 export default MovieTable;
```

**Movies array**

```
const movies = [ {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471815",
    title: "Terminator",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 6,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5,
    publishDate: "2018-01-03T19:04:28.809Z"
}];
```

Comment: `this.setState.movies` I presume this was meant to be `this.state.movies`

Comment: I thought it was convention to set the state by using `setState`?

Comment: @jsilva But with `const movies = this.setState.movies.filter(...)` you are not setting it. You are trying to accessing it which needs to be done by accessing `this.state`. You also did that correctly in other parts of your code so I guess it is a typo? Also the handler must be **inside** the class to be able to access `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you made a typo `this.setState.movies.filter` should be  `this.state.movies.filter` so :

```
handleDelete = movie => {
    const movies = this.state.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id);
    this.setState({ movies });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more context I'm assuming your issue is how you a referencing handleDelete. My primary assumption is that you aren't binding `handleDelete` to `this` in the constructor when using a smart component.

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    
        this.state = {
            movies: null,
        };
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }
    handleDelete = movie => {
        const movies = this.setState.movies.filter(m => m._id !== movie._id);
        this.setState({ movies });
    }
    render() {
      return (<td
        onClick={movie => this.handleDelete(this.props.movie)}
        className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        Delete
      </td>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the `=>` allows me to bind the `this` keyword so I don't have to do `this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);` if I am correct.

Comment: @jsilva You are correct with that. The class property syntax implicitly binds the method to its surrounding context.

Comment: @trixn yeah I am new to React so I am trying to learn day by day. Thanks again for your help!